# Bind Preview of Video : Monodroid

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am trying to bind preview of video to an ImageView. I used the following code,

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.CreateVideoThumbnail("http://***/Content/movie.mp4", ThumbnailKind.MiniKind);
view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.video1).SetImageBitmap (thumbnail);
```

But i get null value in the thumbnail.

What am i doing wrong here.

Any Ideas? 
Thanks.